# Getting Error while installing Angular in my local system?

Tags: angular, installation, node-modules

After downloading the Node on my local laptop (version v16.16.0)

I run this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

For which I got an error on my Windows 10 laptop:

[image: error message for angular]

I expected to get the file to get downloaded:
[image: Expected results]